# How to have title in R Vennerable Venn Diagram?

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I cannot find anything in documentation [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/*checkout*/pkg/Vennerable/inst/doc/Venn.pdf?revision=58&root=vennerable). 
Code

```
library("Vennerable")
data(StemCell)
Vstem <- Venn(StemCell)
Vstem3 <- Vstem[, c("OCT4", "SOX2", "NANOG")]
tl <- "masi"
plot(Vstem3, doWeights = TRUE, type = "circles")
```

Tried unsuccessfully

- `plot(..., main = tl)`
- `plot(..., title = tl)`
- `plot(...); title(tl)`
- `plt <- plot(...); title(plt, tl)`

Fig. 1 Wrong output without title

[image]

R: 3.3.1
OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: No I've not seen it (your questions today were the first time i had heard of this package) , but It is not clear to me what the problem is from looking at the github message

Comment: Sorry, I still dont understand, Im guessing the 821 are the count of ids not in any of the three variables that you retained in your example (from E2F4??). What is the issue here. Your figure in the question (although I dont know what I am looking for ) above looks okay??, and the github issue message is also not clear.

Comment: @user20650 I clarified the wiki with reproducible code https://github.com/js229/Vennerable/issues/40 I also clarified the wiki answer here. - - How can you adjust the proposal (1) here to avoid overlapping of text with figure?

Comment: Thanks. okay, your github;s clearer,  the 2nd example isnt correctly showing the counts. Hopefully the author ersponds. For the title just increase the plot size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

user20650 answer in comments summarised here. Try (1-2) and choose what fits best.

1. The plot method is based on the grid package so the normal base R plot approaches to add a title won't work. Looking at the arguments of `args(Vennerable:::plotVenn)`, there doesn't seem a way to add a title and unhelpfully the plots do not return a grid object. So you can just draw a title on the plot window with the following

   ```
   grid.text("masi", y=0.9, gp=gpar(col="red", cex=2))
   ```
2. As an alternative method, you could grab the grob and then use `grid.arrange` to plot the title

   ```
   gridExtra::grid.arrange(grid::grid.grabExpr(plot(Vstem3, doWeights = TRUE, 
      type = "circles")), top="masi")
   ```

The `grid.arrange` way adds the title as a separate grob, and then they are arranged in two rows. So when resizing the graphics window, it still appears above the plot. This won't be true when drawing straight on the window (as in the first version). 
Note: you do not need to use `gridExtra`, you could do this in grid.

Fig. 1 Output from (1), 
Fig. 2 Output from (2)

[image]
[image]

I think (1) could be better with more adjustments, but now (2) is better.

Comment: You have my vote. I was just typing the same answer.